# A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1

Tags: python, json, python-requests

This is my first post so please forgive any errors.
Problem:
I am receiving the following error while running my code.

A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of config=type

After reading many posts it seems to be a common problem, but I have not found a solution.

My code (with auth details removed):

```
import base64

import requests
from requests import Request, Session

import re
import json

# Developing URL strings with session login
auth_string = user + ':' + password  # preps login
credentials = base64.b64encode(auth_string)  # base 64 is the preferred format for http communication
url_base = 'https://' + esm + '/rs/esm'  # this is the url to send commands to
login_url = url_base + '/login'  # logging in to system

# header for session persistence
login_headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + credentials, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
login_response = requests.post(login_url, headers=login_headers, verify=False)
session = login_response.headers['location']
session_header = {'Authorization': 'Session ' + session, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

# commands to get reports
version = requests.get(url_base + '/getVersion', headers=session_header, verify=False)
dataReturned = requests.post(url_base + '/devGetDeviceList?filterByRights=false', data={"type": "RECEIVER"},
                             headers=session_header, verify=False)

# print results
print(version.content)
print(version.url)
print(dataReturned.url)
print(dataReturned.content)

# terminate session
requests.delete(url_base + '/logout', headers=session_header, verify=False)
```

Here is the output from running the code:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:789: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:789: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:789: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
{"return": {
    "apiMajorVersion": 3,
    "apiMinorVersion": 0,
    "esmMajorVersion": 9,
    "esmMinorVersion": 5,
    "esmPatch": "",
    "esmRevision": 2,
    "esmVersionString": "9.5.2 20160128"
}}
https://IP/rs/esm/getVersion
https://IP/rs/esm/devGetDeviceList?filterByRights=false
A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of type=RECEIVER
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:789: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When describing an error, it's helpful to include the traceback, since that often contains good clues as to what's causing the error.

Comment: The line is: dataReturned = requests.post(url_base + '/devGetDeviceList?filterByRights=false', data={"type": "RECEIVER"},                  headers=session_header, verify=False)

Comment: Normally I do get a trace back error with a line number, this time it just gave the error.

Comment: @Din what if you change `data={"type": "RECEIVER"}` to `data='{"type": "RECEIVER"}'` or do `data=json.dumps({"type": "RECEIVER"})`?

Comment: @jDo Both options return a message from the system saying  >"Must provide a device type"

Comment: @Din ok, both no more `A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of type=RECEIVER`? Is it the API returning `Must provide a device type` or your local system? If it's the API, it's a partial success since your request actually made it out the door :)

Comment: @ jDo yes, no more `A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of type=RECEIVER`

Comment: @Din Ok, then your question is technically answered. I don't know the specific API you're working with (we can't know what your variable `esm` contains and all APIs are different). Next step is to look at the API documentation and find out which options/parameters are required; obviously `device type` must be one of them and I think you would have to add it to the `data={"type": "RECEIVER"}` dictionary before dumping to json and requesting/posting but that's all I can say.

Comment: Just in case anyone else finds this looking for the answer as I was, here is some more detail.  The system is McAfee esm.  The correct line is `dataReturned = requests.get(url_base + '/devGetDeviceList?filterByRights=false',
                            data='{"types": ["RECEIVER"]}',
                            headers=session_header, verify=False)`  and the reason is at: https://community.mcafee.com/thread/89140

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I wrote earlier in the comments, I suspect you're passing in a dictionary where a json object is expected. Hence the error:

> A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of type=RECEIVER

This is a dictionary assigned to the variable `data`:

```
data={"type": "RECEIVER"}
```

And these two are json. Try one of them:

```
data='{"type": "RECEIVER"}'
data=json.dumps({"type": "RECEIVER"})
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me! Now on to the next problem, defining type.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the web service with which you are communicating expects JSON, and you're not providing it.  When you run:

```
dataReturned = requests.post(url_base + '/devGetDeviceList?filterByRights=false',
  data={"type": "RECEIVER"},
  headers=session_header, verify=False)
```

You are sending a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` body with the content:

```
type=RECEIVER
```

If you want to send JSON to the remote server, you need to call `json.dumps`:

```
dataReturned = requests.post(url_base + '/devGetDeviceList?filterByRights=false',
  data=json.dumps({"type": "RECEIVER"}),
  headers=session_header, verify=False)
```

A testing service like http://requestb.in can be tremendously helpful to verify that you are sending the request you think you're sending.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is correct. jDo just beat you by a few min and I can't mark both as answers.